Compare and merge sets from unstructured variables for automatic differentiation
I have developed an automatic differentiation module for my software. Usually AD comes in two forms; forward mode or reverse mode and very clever approaches, beyond me, might mix both. Typically the fastest of these rely on the problems being pre-structured and variables organised consistently to leverage ops.
However, my problems do not have structured variables and they may be dynamically created by users, which means that every mathematical operation that ever occurs always requires a vars check to ensure that vectors are aligned to correctly capture derivatives. Hence this check needs to be as efficient as possible. I have tried to use an Arc pointer since pointer comparisons are almost instantaneous.
Is this is a sensible and efficient approach?  In empirical tests, it seems to work quite well.

/// Struct for defining a dual number data type supporting first order derivatives.
#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone, Default, Debug)]
pub struct Dual {
    real: f64,
    vars: Arc<IndexSet<String>>,
    dual: Array1<f64>,
}

/// Enum defining the `vars` state of two dual number type structs, a LHS relative to a RHS.
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum VarsState {
    EquivByArc,  // Duals share an Arc ptr to their Vars
    EquivByVal,  // Duals share the same vars in the same order but no Arc ptr
    Superset,    // The Dual vars contains all of the queried values and is larger set
    Subset,      // The Dual vars is contained in the queried values and is smaller set
    Difference,  // The Dual vars and the queried set contain different values.
}

/// A trait to order and manage the `variables` of the manifold associated with a dual number.
pub trait Vars where Self: Clone {
    /// Get a reference to the Arc pointer for the `IndexSet` containing the struct's variables.
    fn vars(&self) -> &Arc<IndexSet<String>>;

    /// Create a new dual number with `vars` aligned with given new Arc pointer.
    fn to_new_vars(&self, arc_vars: &Arc<IndexSet<String>>, state: Option<VarsState>) -> Self;

    /// Compare the `vars` on a `Dual` with a given Arc pointer.
    fn vars_cmp(&self, arc_vars: &Arc<IndexSet<String>>) -> VarsState {
        if Arc::ptr_eq(self.vars(), arc_vars) {
            VarsState::EquivByArc
        } else if self.vars().len() == arc_vars.len()
            && self.vars().iter().zip(arc_vars.iter()).all(|(a, b)| a == b) {
            VarsState::EquivByVal
        } else if self.vars().len() >= arc_vars.len()
            && arc_vars.iter().all(|var| self.vars().contains(var)) {
            VarsState::Superset
        } else if self.vars().len() < arc_vars.len()
            && self.vars().iter().all(|var| arc_vars.contains(var)) {
            VarsState::Subset
        } else {
            VarsState::Difference
        }
    }

    /// Construct a tuple of 2 `Self` types whose `vars` are linked by an Arc pointer.
    fn to_union_vars(&self, other: &Self, state: Option<VarsState>) -> (Self, Self) where Self: Sized {
        let state_ = state.unwrap_or_else(|| self.vars_cmp(other.vars()));
        match state_ {
            VarsState::EquivByArc => (self.clone(), other.clone()),
            VarsState::EquivByVal => (self.clone(), other.to_new_vars(self.vars(), Some(state_))),
            VarsState::Superset => (self.clone(), other.to_new_vars(self.vars(), Some(VarsState::Subset))),
            VarsState::Subset => (self.to_new_vars(other.vars(), Some(state_)), other.clone()),
            VarsState::Difference => self.to_combined_vars(other),
        }
    }

    /// Construct a tuple of 2 `Self` types whose `vars` are linked by the explicit union
    fn to_combined_vars(&self, other: &Self) -> (Self, Self) where Self: Sized {
        let comb_vars = Arc::new(IndexSet::from_iter(
            self.vars().union(&other.vars()).map(|x| x.clone()),
        ));
        (self.to_new_vars(&comb_vars, Some(VarsState::Difference)),
         other.to_new_vars(&comb_vars, Some(VarsState::Difference)))
    }

    /// Compare if two `Dual` structs share the same `vars`by Arc pointer equivalence.
    fn ptr_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Arc::ptr_eq(self.vars(), other.vars())
    }
}


I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per site goals: "State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Disclaimer: I know nothing of automatic differentiation, so I won't comment on that aspect.
Formatting
Part of the Rust toolchain is rustfmt, a code formatter, typically invoked via cargo fmt.
It is easier on everyone if you run rustfmt, with mostly default options, on your code, since this way it's formatted like most Rust code out there. It's more comfortable to read code in a familiar style.
Linting
Similarly, the Rust toolchain comes with clippy, a linter, typically invoked via cargo clippy.
It would point that .map(|x| x.clone()) is just a verbose way of saying .cloned(), amongst other things.
Derives
In general, I'd recommend sorting out the derived traits in lexicographic order. It's easier to scan. This means Debug comes before Default.
Your enum VarsState could benefit from a host of supplementary traits: Copy, Eq, Hash would be quite sensible. Perhaps Ord and PartialOrd too.
Naming
VarsState is a poor name.
First of all, I have to question whether the abbreviation, from Variables, is really necessary. Unless it's common in the domain, I'd advise against abbreviation.
But really, it's the State part that bothers me. The very description, and the usage, show it's not describing the state of a set of variables, but instead its relationship to another set of variables.
Thus VariablesSetRelationship, possibly abbreviated as VarsRel if you must, seems a far better description.
Similarly, Equiv can be spelled out as Equivalent.
As an aside, since it is public, the line comment for each alternative should really be documentation comments. Or perhaps it should not be public.
Trait
There's no strong reason for the Vars trait in the sample of code given. It would be far easier to instead implement the functionality as inherent methods over Dual.
Missing abstraction layer
This whole Arc<IndexSet<String>> would do well do be encapsulated.
The implementation of the Vars trait -- if it's ever still necessary after that -- would be quite simpler if the user didn't have to invoke multi-function commands for simple questions.
Furthermore, you could guarantee those questions are answered efficiently. Here is an example implementation on the playground.
/// A set of variables.
///
/// # Partial Order
///
/// A partial order is defined over the sets using inclusion:
///
/// -   Equal: the two sets contain the same elements.
/// -   Greater: a set A is greater than a set B if it is a superset of B.
/// -   Less: a set A is less than a set B if it is a subset of B.
///
/// This order is partial as a set A may neither be a superset nor a subset of
/// of another set B, in which case they are unordered relative to each others.
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vars(Arc<HashSet<String>>);

impl Vars {
    /// Returns the variables within the set.
    ///
    /// The order in which the variables are returned is unspecified.
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> {
        self.0.iter().map(|e| e.as_str())
    }

    /// Returns whether the two vars are equal by pointer.
    pub fn ptr_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Arc::ptr_eq(&self.0, &other.0)
    }

    /// Returns the union of two vars.
    ///
    /// This consumes `self`, in an attempt to reuse its inner allocation. Hence
    /// when creating the union of two vars, if one is a temporary, then the
    /// temporary should be used as the receiver.
    pub fn union(self, other: &Self) -> Self {
        if self.ptr_eq(other) {
            return self;
        }

        let mut set = Arc::unwrap_or_clone(self.0);

        for e in &*other.0 {
            //  FIXME: use `get_or_insert_owned` once stable.
            //  https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get_or_insert_owned
            if !set.contains(e) {
                set.insert(String::from(e));
            }
        }

        Vars(Arc::new(set))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Vars {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.ptr_eq(other) {
            return Some(Ordering::Equal);
        }

        match self.0.len().cmp(&other.0.len()) {
            Ordering::Equal if *self == *other => Some(Ordering::Equal),
            Ordering::Greater if other.0.iter().all(|e| self.0.contains(e)) => {
                Some(Ordering::Greater)
            }
            Ordering::Less if self.0.iter().all(|e| other.0.contains(e)) => {
                Some(Ordering::Less)
            }
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

API footguns
I am concerned about the idea of passing Option<VarsState> as argument, when the API cannot guarantee that the VarsState does, indeed, describe the relationship between the two variables. It makes it easy to accidentally pass the wrong relationship.
For a high-level API you could consider tying together the references:
pub struct VarsRel<'a> {
    rel: VarsState,
    left: &'a Vars,
    right: &'a Vars,
}

Then, any API which consumes this state is at much less risk of accidentally mixing its Vars up.
Simplified vars_cmp
The if ladder in vars_cmp is fairly complex, it could be made more readable by using match.
I'll reuse the new Vars implementation above, since its match does mostly what I want:
    /// Compare the `vars` on a `Dual` with a given Arc pointer.
    fn vars_cmp(&self, arc_vars: &Vars) -> VarsState {
        if self.vars().ptr_eq(arc_vars) {
            return VarsState::EquivByArc;
        }

        match self.vars().partial_cmp(arc_vars) {
            Some(Ordering::Equal) => VarsState::EquivByVal,
            Some(Ordering::Greater) => VarsState::Superset,
            Some(Ordering::Less) => VarsState::Subset,
            None => VarsState::Difference,
        }
    }

Performance: Why String?
It's not clear to me what an IndexSet is -- there's no definition in your code, and don't specify which library it comes from -- so perhaps it's doing something clever with those String. If it's not, I'd really recommend interning.
Interning makes debugging a tad harder, but when each String becomes a u32 (or perhaps a u16 if you're fine with constraining the system to 64K variables) then equality comparison is much faster.
Interning does make ordering comparison harder, but you don't seem to need any of that.
Performance: Arc or Rc or Interning or Clone?
There are many ways to obtain cheap-ish comparisons.
Firstly, one could improve the comparison speed of two IndexSet<String> with each others. Using interned strings and a FxHashSet<u32> would already be an improvement, or if sets are typically dense, a bitset representation could prove quite good. A single CPU cache line has 64 bytes, hence 512 bits. If your problems only have a few thousands variables at most, they'll fit in a handful of cache lines with a bitset representation.
After that, there are alternatives to speed things up further. Not knowing the domain, I cannot know whether:

It's common to update the set of variables of a value -- which here requires cloning the existing set.
It's common to compare the sets of variables of two values.

If updates are semi-common, compared to comparison, then the use of Rc or Arc may backfire.
As to Arc vs Rc, it depends whether the values should be Send (and Sync) or not. If everything is single-threaded, then Rc would have less overhead.
Finally, there's also the alternative of interning not only the variables themselves, but the sets of variables too. Interning comes with interesting properties:

There's no EquivByArc vs EquivByValue difference: once interned, equal is equal.
There are possible savings, allocation-wise, when updating a set, or merging two sets together.

So that's another alternative.

Thanks, this is all very helpful. The IndexSet is used rather than HashSet becuase the order of variables needs to be preserved relative to the dual array, which is a mapping. I realised that strings are less performant but this was chosen as a UI feature. Users can 'name' and reference their variables rather than refer to them with a number - this was considered acceptable performance degradation for the additional feature it gave. I was not aware of string interning or interning at all. Perhaps I will be able to ultilise this. Arc is required over Rc for paralllelisation.
